# DVWA Command Execution High

Tags: dvwa

Has someone done this level? I get that i'm supposed to bypass the trim function, but i don't see how could this be done if every relevant character has been blacklisted except for the redirection (>). There's a similar question posted here but the answers didn't help, they where just hints.

This is what the help states:

The developer has either made a slight typo with the filters and believes a certain PHP command will save them from this mistake.

Spoiler: trim()          removes all leading & trailing spaces, right?.

Thanks

Comment: wasn't DVWA high level not vulnerable at all? Unless you find some new vulnerability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code (https://github.com/RandomStorm/DVWA/blob/master/vulnerabilities/exec/source/high.php) it is definately vulnerable. You just need to take a look at what trim does and what characters are both whitespace and have special meaning on the command line.

https://github.com/RandomStorm/DVWA/issues/78

Answer (score 0):

The high security options are supposed to be the proper implementation. So they are **NOT** exploitable, except you find a new one.

Comment: The old high is now "impossible" and it can be exploited if the server hosting it is vulnerable to shellshock but seems solid otherwise